# Unable to create django queries for the logic required?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, sqlite, django-models

I want to create django query => select those journal names which matches some `ledger1.name` for any particular date range, also filter all transactions in which the ledger name exists in `By` field, and aggregate their 'To' sides total.

I have the following django models:

```
class ledger1(models.Model):
    Creation_Date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32,unique=True)
    group_Name = models.ForeignKey(group1,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Opening_Balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19,decimal_places=2)

class journal(models.Model):
    Date = models.DateField()
    By = models.ForeignKey(ledger1,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='Debitledgers')
    To = models.ForeignKey(ledger1,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='Creditledgers')
    Debit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2,)
    Credit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)
```

thankyou.

Comment: Have you looked at F objects? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions

Comment: unable to find exact queries using F objects!